# Can't deepcopy and append etree element at same time

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, deep-copy

I'm hoping someone can explain this behavior, it gave me quite a headache trying to figure out what was going wrong with my code.

Say we set up some simple etree elements like so

```
from copy import deepcopy
from lxml import etree
elem1=etree.Element('e1')
elem2=etree.Element('e2')
```

If I do this,

```
elem_copy=deepcopy(elem1).append(elem2)
```

`elem_copy` comes out as `NoneType`

However, if I just break out the steps like this

```
elem_copy=deepcopy(elem1)
elem_copy.append(elem2)
```

I get the expected behavior with a new element in `elem_copy` and `elem2` as a child element.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: `append` returns `None`, very simple. If you assign it to a variable, that variable is `None`. `deepcopy()`, on the other hand, returns the copy of an object.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Makes sense, though wasn't intuitive, for me at least

Comment: Because the `append` method of `Element` return `None`.

Comment: You guys are right. I tried with a list as well and got the same result. Wonder how I didn't run into that issue more often. Feel free to leave an answer, then i'll accept to close it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case

```
elem_copy=deepcopy(elem1).append(elem2)
```

the result of `append` i.e. `None` is getting assigned back to `elem_copy`

In the second case

```
elem_copy=deepcopy(elem1)
elem_copy.append(elem2)
```

the result of `append` is not getting assigned back to `elem_copy`. As a result of this, `elem_copy` has the element returned by `deepcopy` with the second element appended to it.

Hope that helps.